# CodeBlocks: How to run after building from custom Makefile

Tags: makefile, g++, codeblocks

I have set up CodeBlocks to build from a custom Makefile. Build is working fine, but I am not able to run the code from CodeBlocks.

To build the project in command prompt, I use simple commands `make` and to clean it is `make clean`. It generates the executable: `main` that I run by `./main`

I am trying to map this to the settings available in codeblocks which has the following values.

- Build project/target: `$make -f
  $makefile $target`
- Compile single
  file: `$make -f $makefile $file`
- Clean project target: `$make -f
  $makefile clean$target`

How can I do the mapping and how to run the project?

Answer (score 2):

Using `makefile` in codeblocks changes the build process only.

The run command is executed according to the Target's output filename.

Go to project [menu] -> properties -> Build Targets [tab]

Set Output Filename to `./main`